# Not hiding DIV until after checkbox is selected or de-selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, checkbox

I'm brand new to javascript so please bear with me. I really appreciate the help. I've got a form I'm using as an assessment exam for people. I have three DIVs and I want them to hide or show depending on how many checkboxes are selected. Here is the issue:

**1. DIVs won't hide until a checkbox has been selected. Javascript doesn't have a value to make function = true or false**

**2. This is my first javascript code and is super messy and log. I would really appreciate if someone could show me a simpler way to accomplish what I'm doing.**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1_0" id="checkbox1_0" class="checkboxA" value="1" />
<label for="checkbox1_0"> Question 1 </label>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1_1" id="checkbox1_1" class="checkboxA" value="1" />
<label for="checkbox1_1">Question 2</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1_2" id="checkbox1_2" class="checkboxA" value="1" />
<label for="checkbox1_2">Question 3</label>

</fieldset>

<p>Total<input type="text" name"TotalChecked" id="TotalCheckedid" size"10" readonly="readonly"         /></p>
     </div>

   <div data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
        <div class="class1")
        <div data-role="collapsible" class="class1" id="class1">
            <h3> Total 0 - 2 </h3>  
         </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible" class="class2" id="class2">
        <h3> Total 3 - 8 </h3>
        </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible"class="class3" id="class3">
    <h3> Total 9 - 25 </h3>
    </div>
```

And then here's the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        recalculate();
}); 

function recalculate() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
    });

// output

$("#TotalCheckedid").val(sum);


}
});

// Show and Hide Class 1, 2 & 3 

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        recalculate();
}); 

function recalculate() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
    });

if (sum >= 1 && sum < 3) {
    ( $("#class1").show());}
else { ( $("#class1").hide())}  
} 
});

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        recalculate();
}); 

function recalculate() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
    });

if (sum >= 3 && sum < 9) {
    ( $("#class2").show());}
else { ( $("#class2").hide())}  
} 
});

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        recalculate();
}); 

function recalculate() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
    });

if (sum >= 9 ) {
    ( $("#class3").show());}
else { ( $("#class3").hide())}  
} 
});
```

Comment: If all checkboxes add 1 each, then it's better to calculate length than iterating for each one. I mean, `var sum = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length`

Comment: more of a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a significantly more condensed version of what you are trying to achieve:

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div").hide();
    $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
        var count = 0;
        $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
            count += $(this).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
        });
        $("div").hide();
        count > 0 && count < 3 ? $("#class1").show().parent().show()
        : count > 2 && count < 9 ? $("#class2").show().parent().show()
        : count > 8 && count < 26 ? $("#class3").show().parent().show()
        : false;
        $("#TotalCheckedid").val(count);
    });
});
```

**See it here:  http://jsfiddle.net/rcz8F/**

I used your exact html in this.

So, here is your breakdown of what's happening.  I'll explain what's happening, line by line.

First, wait until the DOM is loaded.

Then hide all of the div's (this can be chaned to specific selectors if you prefer)

Add an event handler to all of the checkboxes

Define a variable "count"

Loop through each checkbox

If it's checked, add 1 to count, otherwise add 0

Hide all of the div's

If the count is between 1 and 2, show the class1 div and it's parent (since it's nested within another div)

If the count is between 3 and 8, show the class2 div and it's parent

If the count is between 9 and 25, show the class3 div and it's parent

otherwise, do nothing

Update the TotalCheckedid element.

That's all there is to it.  This can be easily changed as needed for your application and it's only 15 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one. I am not clear about your question. May be it should helpful for your exact needs. Please let me know. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>        
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        recalculate();
}); 

function recalculate() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
    });

// output

$("#TotalCheckedid").val(sum);
$('#checkbox1_0').click(function(){
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#class1").show();
    }else{
        $("#class1").hide();
    }   
});
$('#checkbox1_1').click(function(){
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#class2").show();
    }else{
        $("#class2").hide();
    }
});
$('#checkbox1_2').click(function(){
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#class3").show();
    }else{
        $("#class3").hide();
    }
});

}  
});
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1_0" id="checkbox1_0" class="checkboxA" value="1" />
<label for="checkbox1_0"> Question 1 </label>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1_1" id="checkbox1_1" class="checkboxA" value="1" />
<label for="checkbox1_1">Question 2</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1_2" id="checkbox1_2" class="checkboxA" value="1" />
<label for="checkbox1_2">Question 3</label>

</fieldset>

<p>Total<input type="text" name"TotalChecked" id="TotalCheckedid" size"10" readonly="readonly" /></p>
    <div data-role="collapsible" class="class1" id="class1">
        <h3> Total 0 - 2 </h3>  
     </div>

<div data-role="collapsible" class="class2" id="class2">
    <h3> Total 3 - 8 </h3>
    </div>

<div data-role="collapsible"class="class3" id="class3">
<h3> Total 9 - 25 </h3>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```